# cellForRowAtIndexPath: setNeedsDisplay not working for images downloaded in the background, even when calling it on the main thread

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uitableview, setneedsdisplay

I have seen a few posts which suggest using something like the following inside the block which downloads the images asynchronously in order to invoke `setNeedsDisplay`on the main thread and get it to display quicker.

```
dispatch_async(main_queue, ^{
                [view setNeedsDisplay];
            });
```

I'm trying this as can be seen below but the images are not being displayed as soon as they are downloaded. Generally there is about a 4 - 5 second delay. I know this because if I select any particular row, the image appears while the others are still not displayed.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIImageView *iv = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:kCellSubViewWavImageView];;

        //async for scroll performance
        dispatch_queue_t queue = 
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self.user.favWavformURLAr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            NSLog(@"background");
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

            iv.image = image;

            dispatch_queue_t main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
            dispatch_async(main_queue, ^{
                NSLog(@"main thread");
                [iv setNeedsDisplay];
            });

        });

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Incidentally, the `NSLog(@"background");` and `NSLog(@"main thread");` calls below are printed in the following order for the call for the initial 6 cells, which is what I would expect, I think. But still doesn't work:

```
2012-02-17 20:46:27.120 SoundcloudFavs[8836:1c03] background
2012-02-17 20:46:27.169 SoundcloudFavs[8836:1b03] background
2012-02-17 20:46:27.170 SoundcloudFavs[8836:6b07] background
2012-02-17 20:46:27.173 SoundcloudFavs[8836:7503] background
2012-02-17 20:46:27.174 SoundcloudFavs[8836:7103] background
2012-02-17 20:46:27.177 SoundcloudFavs[8836:8003] background
2012-02-17 20:46:27.219 SoundcloudFavs[8836:207] main thread
2012-02-17 20:46:27.270 SoundcloudFavs[8836:207] main thread
2012-02-17 20:46:27.282 SoundcloudFavs[8836:207] main thread
2012-02-17 20:46:27.285 SoundcloudFavs[8836:207] main thread
2012-02-17 20:46:27.296 SoundcloudFavs[8836:207] main thread
2012-02-17 20:46:27.300 SoundcloudFavs[8836:207] main thread
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set downloaded image in main thread.

```
dispatch_async(main_queue, ^{
            NSLog(@"main thread");
            iv.image = image;
        });
```

Also it is better to add images as subviews not for cell but `cell.contentView`.

Comment: Thank you very much... That worked! Can't believe I didn't think of it.